# How to SUMPRODUCT specific columnts

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In the following Excel sheet:

[image: Sheet]

How do I execute SUMPRODUCT of Rate columns (H, M and R) with Hrs columns (I, N and S)? The goal is to get `(170*5+185*1+130*2) + (170*8+185*9+130*10) + ...`, i.e. a total cost for all resources which is $8,885 (same as G3+L3+Q3).

I know how to *isolate* one specific column (e.g. `=SUMPRODUCT(G6:U15*(MOD(COLUMN(G6:U15),5)=3))`) but I am struggling with being able to multiply and then add values from specific columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the following:
`=SUMPRODUCT(H2:H4,I2:I4)+SUMPRODUCT(M2:M4,N2:N4)+SUMPRODUCT(R2:R4,S2:S4)`

you can change H2:H4, I2:I4... to the data you need, I have use your example that is why I set it to have $8,885 as result.

**Update**
For a dynamic column  calculation you can use:

`=SUMPRODUCT(G4:U15*(MOD(COLUMN(G4:U15),5)=3),(H4:V15)*(MOD(COLUMN(H4:V15),5)=4))`

The same formula you are using but you have to use 2 sets of column

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While it certainly contains everything needed for a fixed number of columns, unfortunately, it would not apply to every nth column. The challenge is exactly in that, not having to specify particular column in the formula.